# Finding an upper bound for an integral

Tags: integration

Consider the integral

$$\int_z^\infty \frac{te^{-t^2}}{t^{2N+3}}\,{\rm d}t$$

My lecturer stated that

$$\int_z^\infty \frac{te^{-t^2}}{t^{2N+3}}\,{\rm d}t\le\frac{1}{z^{2N+3}}\int_z^\infty te^{-t^2}\,{\rm d}t = \frac{e^{-z^2}}{2z^{2N+3}}$$

Can anyone state the property that has been used to find the inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard this called "the reciprocal property of inequalities", but I have no reason to think that name is widespread or standard.  Since $t \in [z,\infty)$, $t \geq z$.  But then (as long as $z > 0$ and $N> 3/2$), \begin{align}
    t &\geq z  &&\implies& t^{-1} &\leq z^{-1}  \\
        &&&\implies& t^{-2N+3} &\leq z^{-2N+3}  \text{.}  \\
\end{align}
Then, since the integrand's numerator is positive over $[z,\infty)$, ...

Answer (score 2):

You should write some conditions on $z$ and $N$, but what I see here is that function $\dfrac{1}{t^{2N+3}}$ is decreasing, so it obtains its maximum value at $t=z$.